# Difference between 怒り{いかり} and 怒り{おこり}

Tags: word-choice, nuances, readings, definitions

Both 怒り{いかり} and 怒り{おこり} are nouns and mean "anger".  Even the kanji are the same!

How can we distinguish these two?

Comment: I'm curious about where you've found the word 怒り【おこり】. While it's a theoretically possible form as gerund of 怒る【おこる】, you can hardly hear it from native speakers. Are you asking about 怒る【いかる】 and 怒る【おこる】?

Comment: When I searched for 怒り in an online dictionary, I found out two way of pronunciation おこり and いかり, but I don't know when we pronunciate it as おこり and when as いかり?

Comment: One is an iconic video game from the 80's.

Answer (score 13):

#### As a noun

Only `怒り【いかり】` stands as a noun *anger*, *rage*, *fury* etc. (Accent in Tokyo: いかり{LHH})

#### As a verb gerund (連用形)

It's basically a matter of distinction between `おこる` and `いかる`. Both mean "to get angry, mad or furious", but:

- おこる is more colloquial and tends to describe anger towards real experiences
  ex. おこりっぽい、怒りん{おこりん}坊{ぼう} etc.
- いかる is more literary and tends to describe anger towards abstract notions
  ex. いかり猛【たけ】る、いかり狂【くる】う etc.
- Only おこる has the meaning "to scold"
- Only いかる has the meaning "(things) move wildly, ruggedly"

Thoughtful books and articles usually add furigana when they could be ambiguous. If you can't find furigana, try guessing from the criteria above. If you still feel ambiguity, then either pronunciation might well work, so don't mind.